# Enforcing Supertrait functions on derived impl?

Tags: rust

I just started with Rust and came across this problem. Is there a way to enforce the supertrait on the derived implementation? Or is there any kind of trait grouping?

In this specific case I want to implement a trait which bundles all the basic operator overloadings aka. + - * / += ... and use this trait on different implementations.

Example not acutally valid code:

```rust
//grouping of traits
trait Number: std::ops::Add + std::ops::Sub .... { }

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Complex {
    re: f64,
    im: f64
}

impl Number for Complex {
    // ---snip----
}

//usage
fn main() {
    let a = Complex { re: 1.0, im: 2.0 };
    let b = Complex { re: 3.0, im: 4.0 };
    println!("Result of a + b = {:?}", a + b);
}
```

As I currently understand the supertrait topic I am only able to use those overloaded operators INSIDE the trait definition of the subtrait, is this correct?

Is there any other way to "group" traits like the operator overloading traits to use as a single traitlike entity?

Thanks

Comment: As written (after fixing syntax errors), this code doesn't compile, erroring on `impl Number for Complex`. Is this the error you've got? If not, what is? If yes, what's the intent behind including `main`?

Comment: You may want to consider using [`num::Complex<f64>`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/struct.Complex.html) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @Cerberus i got some more errors resulting from the wronful setup of the `Number` trait. With `...where Self: std::ops::Add<Output = Self> ...` all those errors where resolved and the setup works as intendet.

Comment: @PitaJ thanks for the hint. Since i am just starting with rust, this is a pretty neat excercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when creating a supertrait, you define the trait with the given subtraits:

```
// Grouping of traits
trait Number
where
    Self: std::ops::Add<Output = Self> + std::ops::Sub<Output = Self> + Sized
{}
```

And then you implement that trait for any type that also implements the given subtraits:

```
impl<T> Number for T
where
    Self: std::ops::Add<Output = Self> + std::ops::Sub<Output = Self> + Sized
{}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
fn add<T: Number>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    a + b
}
fn sub<T: Number>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    a - b
}
```

But you'll still need to implement all of the subtraits for any type that you want to use the supertrait with.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5875e3a736a5d56036f229adce5df61)

Comment: Thanks, this works as intended. Can you outline what is the difference between `trait Number where Self: std::ops.....` and `trait Number: std::ops...`? The latter is from the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html) and I am wondering what this is for now.

Comment: The first is just syntax sugar for the second. This way the trait definition and impl can have an identical where clause. I edited the answer to use `Self` in the impl as well.